# How to create a predicate to filter array of enums with associated values in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, filter, enums

```
enum EnumType {
    case WithString(String)
}

var enums = [EnumType]()

enums.append(EnumType.WithString("A"))
enums.append(EnumType.WithString("B"))
enums.append(EnumType.WithString("C"))
enums.append(EnumType.WithString("D"))
enums.append(EnumType.WithString("E"))
enums.append(EnumType.WithString("F"))
```

How to filter my `enums` array to find the one with associated value equal `C`. What **predicate** do I need to use?

Comment: What's the purpose of an enum with no enumerated values? You're just creating an array/list of String elements. However, filtering an array is easy: let filteredArray = array.filter { $0 matches condition }

Comment: I will use it in a more complex example:-) but the essence is in the SIMPLEST example

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The filter function can either be invoked as a global function over an array, or as an instance method (I prefer the later as it is more OO).

It accepts a closure with one parameter (the element being evaluated) that return a boolean (indicating whether the element matches the required condition).

Since it's a simple closure in a clear situation it's ok to use the abbreviated form.

I guess that other "With" cases would be added to your enum, so you could go with something like:

```
let filteredArray = enums.filter { 
    switch $0 {
      case .withString(let value):
        return value == "C"
      default:
        return false
    }
 }
```

That should do the trick in your example.

Comment: No, it is not the trick... It is not example with `rawValue`.

Answer (score 11):

As someone already mentioned, for Swift > 2.0 there's **if case** statement available:

```
enums.filter {
  if case .WithString("C") = $0 {
    return true
  }
  return false
}
```

But, it doesn't look nice, especially if you are going to repeat same logic again. What we can do here is to make **EnumType** conform to Equatable:

```
extension EnumType: Equatable {
}

func ==(lhs: EnumType, rhs: EnumType) -> Bool {
    switch (lhs, rhs) {
    case (.WithString(let lStr), .WithString(let rStr)):
        return lStr == rStr
    }
}
```

And now you can just:

```
enums.filter { $0 == .WithString("C") }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding a simple extension with a computed property to your enum and filter to that property:

```
extension EnumType {
  var isC: Bool {
    switch self {
    case .WithString(let message): return message == "C"
    default: return false
    }
  }
}
```

After this, you could simpy use the filtering as usual:

```
enums.filter { $0.isC }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var filteredArray = enums.filter { element in
    switch element {
    case EnumType.WithString(let string):
        return string == "A"
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

This can probably be simplified with Swift 2.0 binding of assosciated values in `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [@Jessy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/652038/jessy) and [SwiftLee](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/reflection-how-mirror-works/), here is my solution:

```
// -----------------------
//     CaseReflectable
// -----------------------

// designed for enums only 
// (use it on other types not recommended)
protocol CaseReflectable {}

// default behaviors.
extension CaseReflectable {
    
    /// case name
    var caseName: String {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        // enum cases:
        // - normal case: no children
        // - case with associated values: one child (with label)
        guard let label = mirror.children.first?.label else {
            return "\(self)"    // normal case
        }
        // case with associated values
        return label
    }
    
    /// associated values
    var associatedValues: Any? {
        
        // if no children, a normal case, no associated values.
        guard let firstChild = Mirror(reflecting: self).children.first else {
            return nil
        }
        
        return firstChild.value
    }
}

// --------------------------
//     custom operator ~=
// --------------------------

/// match enum cases with associated values, while disregarding the values themselves.
/// usage: `Enum.enumCase ~= instance`
func ~= <Enum: CaseReflectable, AssociatedValue>(
    // an enum case (with associated values)
    enumCase: (AssociatedValue) -> Enum,    // enum case as function
    // an instance of Enum
    instance: Enum
) -> Bool 
{
    // if no associated values, `instance` can't be of `enumCase`
    guard let values = instance.associatedValues else { return false }
    // if associated values not of the same type, return false
    guard values is AssociatedValue else { return false }
    // create an instance from `enumCase` (as function)
    let case2 = enumCase(values as! AssociatedValue)
    // if same case name, return true
    return case2.caseName == instance.caseName
}

// ------------
//     Enum
// ------------

// enum with associated values
// (conforms to `CaseReflectable`)
enum Enum: CaseReflectable {
    case int(Int)
    case int2(Int)
    case person(name: String, age: Int)
    case str(String)
}

// ------------
//     main
// ------------

let a: Enum = .int(3)

Enum.int ~= a        // true
Enum.int2 ~= a       // false

let joe = Enum.person(name: "joe", age: 8)

Enum.person ~= joe   // true
Enum.int ~= joe      // false

// array of enum cases
let items: [Enum] = [
    .int(1), .str("hi"), .int(2)
]

// filter enum cases
let filtered = items.filter { Enum.int ~= $0 }
print(filtered)      // [Enum.int(1), Enum.int(2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something more reusable by implementing `Equatable` protocol:

```
enum EnumType {
    case WithString(String)
}

extension EnumType: Equatable {

    static func ==(lhs: EnumType, rhs: String) -> Bool {
        switch lhs {
        case .WithString(let value):
            return value == rhs
        }
    }
}

EnumType.WithString("F") == "A" // false
EnumType.WithString("F") == "F" // true
```